# Creating a custom estimator

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, data-science

A federal agency, Centers for Medicare and Medicaid Services (CMS), imposes regulations on nursing homes. However, nursing homes are inspected by state agencies for compliance with regulations, and fines for violations can vary widely between states.

Let's develop a very simple initial model to predict the amount of fines a nursing home might expect to pay based on its location. Fill in the class definition of the custom estimator, StateMeanEstimator, below.

> i am getting the following (error Your solution did not match the expected type: 53 * number
> Specifically, solution[52] did not match {'type': 'number'}:
> None)

Here is my code

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin, TransformerMixin
```

class GroupMeanEstimator(BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin):
def **init**(self, grouper):
self.grouper = grouper
self.group_averages = {}

```
def fit(self, X, y):
    # Use self.group_averages to store the average penalty by group
    Xy = X.join(y)
    state_mean_series = Xy.groupby(self.grouper)[y.name].mean()
    for row in pd.DataFrame(state_mean_series).itertuples():
        self.group_averages[row[0]] = row[1]
    return self

def predict(self, X):
    # Return a list of predicted penalties based on group of samples in X
    if not isinstance(X, pd.DataFrame):
        X = pd.DataFrame(X)
    dictionary = self.group_averages
    group = self.grouper
    list_of_predictions = []
    for row in X.itertuples():
        prediction = dictionary.get(row.STATE)
        list_of_predictions.append(prediction)
    return list_of_predictions
```

Comment: Without data that reproduces the problem, SO can't be of much help. Please review Jon Skeet's excellent blog post [WRITING THE PERFECT QUESTION](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) for guidance in updating your question.  For a more detailed tutorial on asking a good question see Eric S. Raymond's site [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Comment: Plese read the description of the [tag:ml] tag.